# Best way to achieve dynamic cell height for an UIImageView inside a tableViewCell?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiimageview

Trying to have smooth dynamic height, currently it works but it glitches from one size to the dynamic size with doesn't look good.

Heres my code inside `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

```
 cell.productImageView.file = (PFFile *)object[@"image"];
 [cell.productImageView loadInBackground:^(UIImage * _Nullable image, NSError * _Nullable error) {


            cell.imageHeightConstraint.constant = image.size.height / image.size.width * cell.cardView.frame.size.width;
            [cell.productImageView setNeedsUpdateConstraints];

            NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];
            if (indexPath != nil) {
                [self.tableView beginUpdates];
                [self.tableView endUpdates];
            }

            [UIView animateWithDuration:0.50f animations:^{
                [cell.cardView layoutIfNeeded];
            }];

     }];
```

So as you can see, I'm just updating the height constraint of the ImageView and then the cell resizes accordingly. But still glitchy.

Is there a better way?

Comment: You shouldn't be messing with layout in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. There's a `heightForRowAtIndexPath` method that you should implement to set the row height.

Comment: Could you show me a programatic solution? @user3386109

Comment: create a custom cell xib and use auto layout constraints.

Comment: Whats the advantage of using xib?

Comment: @user3386109 im not changing the height of the cell in the code, im changing the height of the imageView

Answer (score 1):

You can solve your problem to adding following lines in `viewDidLoad` and `autolayout`.

```
_tblView.delegate = self;
_tblView.dataSource = self;
self._tblView.estimatedRowHeight = 80; // The estimatedRowHeight but if is more this autoincremented with autolayout
self._tblView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
[self._tblView setNeedsLayout];
[self._tblView layoutIfNeeded];
self._tblView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(20, 0, 0, 0) ;
```

Here is More information:

https://www.raywenderlich.com/87975

http://candycode.io/automatically-resizing-uitableviewcells-with-dynamic-text-height-using-auto-layout/

I hope, it will help you..!